# How to get the current working directory in Ballerina?

Tags: operating-system, ballerina

In Ballerina, is there a way to programmatically get the current working directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `exec` function in `ballerina/os` package. Refer to the sample below.

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/os;

public function main() returns error? {
    os:Command cmd = {value: "pwd"};
    os:Process proc = check os:exec(cmd);
    string pwd = check string:fromBytes(check proc.output(io:stdout));
    io:println(pwd);
}
```

Refer to the API Docs : https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/os/latest#exec

OS module spec definitions : https://ballerina.io/spec/os/#4-operating-system-command-execution

Comment: IMO, this capability should be part of the `ballerina:os` package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getCurrentDir` function in the `ballerina/file` package. Please refer to the API Docs: https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/file/1.2.1#getCurrentDir